# MariaDb and Httpd getting killed due to memory

Tags: centos, vps, httpd, mariadb, kill

I have a Centos7 VPS on OVH with this settings:

- 1Virtual Core
- 1  GB Ram
- 10 GB Raid 10

I have running on it 3 wordpresses. One of them is still on building (0 access to public), other has very few people watching it, and the other has many views per day).

Since the beggining, MariaDB has been killed by OOM. Today, it was httpd turn to get killed.

My ovh manager says the vps is around 500mb ram, never up that.

This is my mariadb conf:
http://pastie.org/private/jwo5nrptfissi3i4zk0g

I don't know what else to do, cant find a solution to this.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please don't show config info as screenshots. Use copy/paste either here or into some snippet site  if it gets too long.

Comment: Removed screenshots.

Comment: Have you considered... adding memory?

Comment: It's a way, but wanted that to be the last options, as the price will triplicate.

Answer (score 0):

configure http and mariadb to use less memory and process. Defaults aren't always good especially on a shared 1G instance.

Your innodb_buffer_pool_size indicates you aren't using innodb. It should be more if you are.

You shouldn't set thread_stack - leave it as default.

Have you increased max_allowed_packet for a reason.

I'd suspect most of the usage is in httpd. Run with less processes.